# Android Java.util.Arrays class

Tags: java, android, arrays

This is probably a question with a blindingly obvious answer.  I just can't see it, and will probably feel very small when someone points it out to me clearly.

I'm using Android at the Eclair MR1 level, so my Android Manifest has:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

In my MainActivity, I have a byte[] that I want to realloc to a larger size.

Java SE 6 has the java.util.Arrays class with static methods to do that for every elementary type.  I can see that class documented in the android docs at [http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28byte[],%20int%29](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28byte%5B%5D,%20int%29)

Here's my code:

```
    byte [] padToLength (byte[] plain) {

    try{
        byte[] plainpad2 = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(plain, plain.length+10);  //why won't this compile?
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

But when I use that, I get a compilation error in Eclipse, saying "the method copyOf(byte[], int) is undefined for the type Arrays.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What's your target sdk?  Have you tried building with sdk version 9?  If the method is available since API 9, then you'll need to build against that or later?

Comment: @Peter vdL: You can probably use the static method [`System.arraycopy (Object src, int srcPos, Object dst, int dstPos, int length)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) in stead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arrays.copyOf(byte[], int)` is not defined for API Level 7. At that link you provided, have a look in the top-right corner and you'll see a checkbox that says "Filter By API Level". Selecting `7` removes that method.

Why are you working with arrays anyway? In Java you should almost always use `ArrayList` unless you are experiencing performance problems. In that case, you don't have to worry about the size of your array at all. If your function must accept a `byte[]` parameter, then I'd suggest invoking something like `List<Byte> myList = Arrays.asList(plain)`.

Comment: You and MH nailed it, and I feel suitably small.   This API came in with API level 9.  Thank you!  As you guessed, performance is the top priority, which is why I am working with arrays of atomic types.